# Is it possible to restore PATH?

Tags: terminal, path

So I accidentally run in terminal command `export PATH="/usr/bin/php/bin"` which override my defaults and none of the commands aren't responding.

```
MacBook-Pro-Kil:home $ sudo
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Is it possible somehow restore it? My system is 10.9.5

Comment: Your path is bind to your session. Open a new terminal window and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’re not willing to give up your active terminal session, try to bootstrap your settings like this:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin; source ~/.bash_profile
```

The part that says `export PATH=…` is there to bootstrap an environment for `~/.bash_profile`, which might itself rely on one or more of the paths given.